# package for combine js files into one file (atom or sublime text)

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, atom-editor

Is there any package for sublime text or atom editor to combine many js files into one file ? like SASS for css or any easy way for do this work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [Gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat/) to merge JS files, requires [Gulp task runner](http://gulpjs.com), which works with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/).